# Get the output path or the ".xcresult" file of "xcodebuild test"

Tags: bash, xcodebuild

I am working on a bash script which executes UI tests via `xcodebuild` and I am looking for a way to retrieve the path where the test results (the `.xcresult` file) are generated

After I execute a command `xcodebuild test -workspace ... -scheme ... -xcconfig ... -destination ...` and after all tests run I see an output like:

```
Test session results, code coverage, and logs:
    /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-name/Logs/Test/Test-proj-name-2023.09.20_13-17-52-+0300.xcresult
```

Is there a way I can retrieve that path or even better copy that file to a new location via a bash script

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-resultBundlePath` argument when running `xcodebuild test ...` to specify a specific path for Xcode to use.

```
$ man xcodebuild
...
     -resultBundlePath path
           Writes a bundle to the specified path with results from performing an action on a scheme in a workspace. If the path already exists, xcodebuild will exit with an error. Intermediate directories will be created
           automatically. The bundle contains build logs, code coverage reports, XML property lists with test results, screenshots and other attachments collected during testing, and various diagnostic logs.
```

For example, this is a path relative to the calling location:

```
$ xcodebuild -project Single-Static-Framework-Project.xcodeproj -scheme ObjcFrameworkTests -destination "id=7A180605-34A2-4644-916A-08D1975871FE" -quiet -resultBundlePath TestSlowness.xcresult test
...
Writing result bundle at path:
    [REDACTED]/rules_ios/tests/ios/xcodeproj/TestSlowness.xcresult
...
```